# Read words after and before some words from TXT file and Convert to CSV

Tags: regex, powershell, export-to-csv

I wrote a script which has to read the txt file, find all the words which are after "CN" and before "," and export them into csv.

```
$TXTFile = "C:\original.txt" 
    Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
           Out-File "C:\Output.txt"
           Export-Csv "C:\Output.csv"
```

The Problem is the "Output.txt" gives me the correct result but "Output.csv" gives me the length of founded CNs.
what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not enough to call a file ".csv" to get a csv. A csv is a comma separated file consisting of datasets (rows) with various properties (columns).

Out-File cmdlet is simply generating a text file. For generating csv use Export-CSV. But this will only work with an array of objects as imput. You simply have an array of strings.

I changed the Script and now it works:

```
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
  select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
  Export-CSV $CSVFile -noTypeInformation
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.